# C# ASP.MVC Get checkbox value using Html.EditFor and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Just wondering, Imagine I have a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="situationcontrol" name="situationcontrol">
```

I could check if this is checked or not by using this JavaScript code:

```
var situationcontrol = $("#situationcontrol").prop('checked');
```

Now I am wondering how this would work if you make a checkbox using  `@Html.EditorFor`

Like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model =>Model.ServiceDeliveryMutableObjects.SituationControl)
```

I tried to change the same javascript code with the new generated ID

```
var situationcontrol = $("#ServiceDeliveryMutableObjects.SituationControl").prop('checked');
```

But that doesnt seems to work.
Any Idea how this would work?

Thanks

Edit: When I inspect element in browser when I use `@Html.EditFor`
[image]

Comment: Could you also post the html generated by @Html.EditorFor(model =>Model.ServiceDeliveryMutableObjects.SituationControl)?

Comment: @VivekSingh I updated the question with a image. This is what I get when I right click -> Inspect element in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Didn't snap to that until you posted the rendered output. The `.` is not valid in HTML ids, so Razor uses underscores instead. So, the id you should be selecting is `#ServiceDeliveryMutalObjects_SituationalControl`, rather than `#ServiceDeliveryMutalObjects.SituationalControl`. Other than that, the rest of my original answer applies.

**ORIGINAL**

First, actually it's better to use:

```
$('#foo').is(':checked')
```

Now, as for using `EditorFor`, *technically*, this doesn't change anything. The id will obviously be based on the object graph, i.e. `#ServiceDeliveryMutalObjects_SituationalControl`, but nothing changes about the actual rendering of the HTML element. I emphasized "technically", here, because while that should be case, there's no default editor template that will actually render a checkbox input. The default is a text box, and a text box, obviously will not have a `checked` property. This can be corrected by either:

1. Use `CheckBoxFor` instead. That way, you're assured of getting an actual checkbox input.
2. Assuming this property is a boolean, you can create the view `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Boolean.cshtml` with something like:

   ```
   @model bool?
   @Html.CheckBox("", Model)
   ```

   Then, `EditorFor` will use this template, and generate a checkbox input.

Finally, it may just be a typo in your question, but you want lowercase "model", not "Model", on the right side of your expression. In other words, it needs to match the left side of the lambda. I tend to avoid using `model` in these expressions, as not only is it more to type than needed, but you can easily get confused between "model" and "Model", especially with Intellisense's autocomplete. For example,

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ServiceDeliveryMutableObjects.SituationControl)
```

Comment: If you want you can also specify the id and other properties using the With {.id = "thisorthat", .checked="false"} syntax

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code like this

```
Var situationcontrol =  $("#ServiceDeliveryMutableObjects_SituationControl").prop('checked');
```

You need to remove .in Id of elements in **mvc reazor view it's will convert '.' To '_'** when we provide in elements name.